# iPhone App runtime error- "Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.\n"

Tags: iphone

This error

```
Thu Apr  8 20:24:15 iPod-touch appname[947] <Error>: Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.\n
Thu Apr  8 20:24:16 iPod-touch appname[947] <Error>: Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.\n
```

is logged when a UIImageView is loaded. The view isn't huge but it has a few other UIImageViews as subviews and it might be related to memory, but I can't find anything on this message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the image file might be malformed.  Have you tried opening the image in Preview and re-saving it?

Comment: You were right. I had tried resaving in GIMP but for some reason that didn't work and resaving it in Preview did.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't add another UIImageView as a subView to the UIImageView.

we can add UIImage as a subView to the UIImageView

Try it by creating testing project.