# What does the "Embedded profile header length is greater than data length." error mean?

Tags: iphone

When I run my application on my iPhone, I receive these warnings in the console:

```
  <Error>: Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.

  <Error>: Error: Embedded profile signature is not valid.
```

What do these warnings mean, and how can I resolve them?

Comment: Please provide more info about your app

Comment: I've notice this as well, but only since I started using Xcode 4. Is that your situation as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone App runtime error- "Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.\n"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604686/iphone-app-runtime-error-error-embedded-profile-header-length-is-greater-than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you looked here [iPhone App runtime error- "Error: Embedded profile header length is greater than data length.\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604686/iphone-app-runtime-error-error-embedded-profile-header-length-is-greater-than)